# How to turn off Safari opening previous page when using Command+Z?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, safari

I've noticed recently in Safari, in some cases, if I press Command+z that it will open the previously opened browser tab.

It's messing up my web application. Sometimes it correctly performs Undo and others it is opening the previous page (when there is no more undo history). Is this a bug or is it a feature I can turn off in JavaScript or HTML? My application does not always have the cursor inside a text field so I need to prevent Safari taking the event.

This is Mac OSX 10.11, Safari 10.1.

Safari changing from Undo Typing to Undo Close Tab:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a listener to the window object for the keypress event and called  preventDefault() on the event:

```
function preventDefaultWindowOpen(prevent) {
    var isSafari;
    var useCapture = true;
    const KEYTYPE = "keypress";

    if (navigator.vendor && navigator.vendor.indexOf('Apple') > -1 && 
        navigator.userAgent && !navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS')) {
        isSafari = true;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

    if (window.preventOpenOnUndoKey==null) {
        window.preventOpenOnUndoKey = function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode==122 && event.metaKey==true) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }

    if (prevent) {
        window.addEventListener(KEYTYPE, window.preventOpenOnUndoKey, useCapture);
    }
    else {
        window.removeEventListener(KEYTYPE, window.preventOpenOnUndoKey, useCapture);
    }

    return true;
}

preventDefaultWindowOpen(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly right:  "Safari is stealing the undo keyboard event from my web page."

That's what's happening. Safari steals the CMD-Z from your keyboard that'd normally be sent into Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

While it looks like [this](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) might be worth reading, I'd recommend against this practice and instead look into the way your application is built. Re-opening a previously closed tab is a common action people perform in the web browser and your application should be able to handle this.

Comment: Safari has undo and redo keyboard shortcuts. It seems like if there is no more additional undo events in the undo history stack Safari reloads the previous page. Safari is changing it's behavior. This is upsetting to my users. Safari is thinking it's doing the right thing but in this case it's making assumptions. I'm trying to maintain the correct behavior.

Comment: "It seems like if there is no more additional undo events in the undo history stack Safari reloads the previous page."

What do you mean? I just closed Safari, opened it again, went to google.com and pressed cmd+z and nothing happened. It doesn't reload anything.

Comment: I've added a screenshot. Safari is stealing the undo keyboard event from my web page.

Comment: It isn't stealing it -- that's part of the web browsers functionality. Does your web application have a function mapped to cmd+z? If so, I'd recommend changing that as the browser has a clearly defined behavior for cmd+z.

Comment: That is to undo the last action. If you type into a text input the CMD+z will undo the text you type. If you don't want to help that's fine I'm done with this conversation.

Comment: My apologies -- I don't mean to seem rude. All I'm suggesting is that cmd+z has a clearly defined function within Safari. I'm still not sure what you mean when you say cmd+z causes a page refresh. I can't seem to replicate it myself.

Hopefully someone else here can offer you some assistance :)

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. There are some behaviors that are built into an application or framework that add a default action. But if you don't want to use that action and if the SDK allows it then you can call event.preventDefault() and prevent it. In this case, Safari determined created a condition where Undo keyboard command would open a previous window if there was nothing in the Undo stack. This is not the expected action in my application which is why I needed to explain what I want from the browser.